# Why is my code printing such large numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this code:

```
count = -1
with open("group.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
with open("group2.txt", "r") as f:
    mydict = eval(f.read())
print(content)
for x in range(0, len(mydict)):
    count += 1
    content = content.replace(str(mydict.keys()[count]), str(mydict.values()[count]))
with open("group3.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

It should replace all the `mydict.keys()` with the `mydict.values()`.

When I run it; it prints very long numbers.

Here is the original line:

```
<VertexRef> { 0 1 2 <Ref> { vpool } }
```

It is printed as this:

```
<VertexRef> { 81131131213851461468215053091131131401466142513121386133513091131131421505309113113140146614251312138613351296 81131131213851461468215053091131131401466142513121386133513091131131401466142771 811311312138514614682150530911311314014661425131213861335130911311394 <Ref> { vpool } }
```

It should be:

```
 <VertexRef> { 754 755 756 <Ref> { vpool } }
```

[group.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ids5ig8q103djpe/group.txt)

[group2.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jhm14r4vajo8y4j/group2.txt)

Comment: `mydict = eval(f.read())` Whenever you find yourself using eval, you know there MUST be a better way. In your case, it is [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), if you must write it to a file at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must replace them simultaneously. What you're doing is replacing numbers one by one.

Let's say these are your replacements:

```
1: 423
2: 32
3: 14
4: 31
```

and your content is `"1"`. After each loop, you get this:

```
0: 1
1: 432
2: 4332
3: 414142
4: 311311312
```

Unfortunately, AFAIK Python does not have a cool replace function that takes in arrays of searches and replaces, so you can do several other things instead:

a) Make sure unreplaced numbers are recognisable. For example, first surround all numbers with square brackets (or anything else that you know the content does not already have), using regular expressions; then look for `[1]` and replace with `432`, look for `[2]` and replace with `32` etc; this way you're explicitly marking what you are done with and what you still need to do

b) Use a regular expression that picks up all numbers (`"\d+"`) and for replacement have a *function* that will look up the correct replacement. This is in effect the simultaneous solution, and is the one I recommend. No loop required.

Comment: How do I replace them simultaneously?

Comment: Sorry, took time to write it out.